# Finding words from two properties in a mongodb document

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to find a word from two properties (columns) 'firstname' and 'lastname' from a document. The code below is not giving the response while finding from multiple properties. I am new to mongo db please make me aware of my mistake and its possible solution.

```
router.get('/search/:user', (req, res) => {
  const searchField = new RegExp(req.params.user, 'i');
  User.find({ firstname: { $regex: searchField }, lastname: { $regex: searchField } })
    .then((data) => {
      res.json(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

It is working when I pass a single property though. How can I make it possible to find from both 'firstname' and 'lastname' at once.

Comment: are you trying to find a word that is contained in either of the attributes or does it have to be present in both?

Comment: Either one of the attributes. @Alejandro

Comment: $or may be what you need. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

Comment: yup, what you need is $or operation as follows: find({  $or: [   {Query1}, {Query2}   ]  })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rohit Dalal's answer is the correct solution.

```
User.find({ $or: [{ firstname: { $regex: searchField } }, { lastname: { $regex: searchField } }] })
```

This is the desired solution.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28373010)

Comment: I have edited my answer and included the solved code.